# CodeDeploy after CodeBuild

Tags: continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy, aws-codebuild

When I try to do CodeDeploy after CodeCommit, all files are sent to the server as normal. But when I use CodeBuild between them, only CodeDeploy gives an error.

**The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.**

`buildspec.yml`

[image: buildspec.yml]

`appspec.yml`

[image: appspec.yml]

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs when your EC2 instance does not have CodeDeploy agent installed or running. AWS docs has a full troubleshooting section for this issue: [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-skipped-lifecycle-events)